# Error Importing with scss @import in storybook

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-style-loader, storybook

I am starting to use storybook in a different project, I have gotten SCSS @import to work before in another repo but I cant figure out for the life of me what is wrong.

> ERROR in ./src/components/Navigation/style.scss
>   (./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-1!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/components/Navigation/style.scss)
>   Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> @import '../../styles/vars/colors'; ^
>
> Invalid CSS after "'": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "'use strict';"

My webpack config inside of .storybook

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill'],

  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.stories\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: [require.resolve('@storybook/addon-storysource/loader')],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              import: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [
                require('autoprefixer')({
                  overrideBrowserslist: [
                    '>1%',
                    'last 4 versions',
                    'Firefox ESR',
                    'not ie < 9'
                  ]
                })
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
          name: 'assets/images[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              disable: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
};
```

The versions of relevant packages:
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.1.4",
    "file-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.5",
    "style-loader": "0.17.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.0.1",

Comment: Maybe [this discussion](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/4306#issuecomment-428821849) will shed some light

Comment: Also this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/preset-scss

Comment: If you have this issue with Angular 13, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69709805/using-global-stylesheets-with-storybook-angular-sasserror-sasserror-expect/71103263#71103263

Answer (score 1):

Although am not certain in which context you are using this import, I've had similar problems when omitting the file extension from a SCSS file import.

Try using this syntax:

```js
@import '../../styles/vars/colors.scss';
```